Altering the stored procedure does not affect the output
In the context of the provided SQL Server stored procedure, I need  the SCODE column in myTable to be a value of 0, regardless of the values present in the @TVP_m table.
I have tried:
INSERT INTO [ax].myTable ([AMOUNT], [SUM], [UNIT], [ID],
                          [DATE], [SCODE],   -- The value type is INT
                          [TIME])
    SELECT
        [AMOUNT], [SUM], [UNIT], [ID],
        [DATE], 0,         -- The value type is INT
        [TIME]
    FROM 
        @TVP_m AS Source;

But still no affect, the table value is set by temp table
This is the whole stored procedure:
ALTER PROCEDURE [crt].[INSERTSA]
    @bId   BIGINT,
    @TVP_S [crt].[RETAILSTABLETYPEV2] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @i_R     INT;
    DECLARE @i_T     INT;
    DECLARE @i_Error INT;

    SET @i_R = 0;
    SET @i_T = 0;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        SELECT @i_Error = @@ERROR;

        IF @i_Error <> 0
        BEGIN
            SET @i_R = @i_Error;
            GOTO exit_label;
        END;

        SET @i_T = 1;
    END;

    -- Perform Insert
    INSERT INTO [ax].RETAILTNS ([AMOUNT], [SUM], [UNIT], [ID],
                                [DATE], [SCODE], [TIME], [CHANNEL])
        SELECT
            [AMOUNT], [SUM], [UNIT], [ID],
            [DATE], [SCODE], [TIME], @bId
        FROM @TVP_S AS Source;

    SELECT @i_Error = @@ERROR;

    IF @i_Error <> 0
    BEGIN
        SET @i_R = @i_Error;
        GOTO exit_label;
    END;

    IF @i_T = 1
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;

        SET @i_Error = @@ERROR;

        IF @i_Error <> 0
        BEGIN
            SET @i_R = @i_Error;
            GOTO exit_label;
        END;

        SET @i_T= 0;
    END;

    exit_label:

    IF @i_T = 1
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;

    RETURN @i_R;
END;

First I need to know why the altered stored procedure does not set the value to 0.
Secondly can someone please provide guidance on how to modify the code to achieve this requirement, ensuring that the CODE column is always initialized with a value of 0?

@DaleK But Why  the SP code doesn't include that ? and how can i force my SP to include that ?

@DaleK I select the SP , right click select the modify option , after changing click on execute ... to make sure of all the changes I restarted the server check the SP , it was modified but no effect ...

I have no idea what you mean... you should just be running the alter procedure script you show in a SSMS window. As it stands you have a bunch of syntax errors, maybe thats why its not updating? https://dbfiddle.uk/cafGBlos

What is @@TCOUNT, should that be @@TRANCOUNT. I recommend that you format your code (indentation etc.) as it's nigh on impossible to read.

@SteveFord I did the formatting thanks

I just tried to run you latest edits of your SP and get the following error Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1. - so clearly its not working yet regardless of 0/non-0.

Here is a demonstration showing just the select (I have hardcoded the input to save creating the table type) and see it shows first the original value of scode and then just 0 https://dbfiddle.uk/mtwDNKwP

Thats pretty wacky error handling... I didn't look in detail, but I think its well over complicated.

@DaleK I don't see any option to accept an answer!!!

Modify the INSERT statement within the stored procedure to explicitly set the SCODE value to 0. Then ensure that the rest of the columns are correctly mapped from the @TVP_m table:
USE [RetailStore4567]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [crt].[INSERTDETAILS]
@Id           BIGINT,
@TVP_m          [crt].[myTABLETYPEV2]    READONLY
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @i_RC       INT;
    DECLARE @i_T        INT;
    DECLARE @i_E        INT;
    
    IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        SELECT @i_E = @@ERROR;
        IF @i_E != 0
        BEGIN
            SET @i_RC = @i_E;
            GOTO exit_label;
        END;

        SET @i_T = 1;
    END;

    -- Performing Insert into myTable

    INSERT INTO [ax].myTable
    (
        [AMOUNT],
        [SUM],
        [UNIT],
        [ID],
        [DATE],
        [SCODE], -- The value type is INT
        [TIME]
    ) 
    SELECT
        [AMOUNT],
        [SUM],
        [UNIT],
        [ID],
        [DATE],
        0, -- Explicitly set SCODE to 0
        [TIME]
    FROM @TVP_m AS Source;

    SELECT @i_E = @@ERROR;
    IF @i_E != 0
    BEGIN
        SET @i_RC = @i_E;
        GOTO exit_label;
    END;

    IF @i_T = 1
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;

        SELECT @i_E = @@ERROR;
        IF @i_E <> 0
        BEGIN
            SET @i_RC = @i_E;
            GOTO exit_label;
        END;

        SET @i_T = 0;
    END;

exit_label:

    IF @i_T = 1
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;

    RETURN @i_RC;
END;


But actually the main change you have made is fix all the existing syntax errors - so worth pointing that out because its likely that is what was stopping OP from altering the SP.

@DaleK , actually in my actual code there is no error , When i posted I made some syntax error ( now i modified and there is no error  )

@player0   Belive me i did try to Explicitly set SCODE to 0 but did not work ... Should i just write the SP again ... I have mentioned that i did try but no affect is seen ...

@Roberto you must have done something wrong somewhere, because if you insert 0, you are inserting zero. Given we can't see what you've done, we can't really help.

@Roberto so what was the fix in the end? You originally said this didn't work - so what did you change that solved your issue?

@DaleK , Thanks , I've just forced SQL Server to use the latest version of my SP
EXEC sp_recompile N'dbo.mySP 

Hmmm... thats very weird.
